# What if the DB coin stake is exceeded by the incentive to misbehave?

Tags: polybase

If protocols built with [Polybase](https://docs.polybase.xyz) base their own rewards on DB data, could a bad DB indexer not abuse its storage power?

I just wanted to understand more on the Polybase incentive structure and how you guys make sure that there is no bad actor in the network? If there is a bad guy, how do you deal with it?

Answer (score 2):

Using zk-snarks means that most clients on the network can easily validate an action end-to-end and refuse to accept an invalid one. Therefore, you would get slashed, and still not achieve your objective.

The root hash/proof on the blockchain is the most important, as it validates all other proofs, and that inherits its security from the L1 (e.g. Near or Ethereum).

The slashing is mostly used to prevent people from spamming the network with false claims.

Source: [Polybase whitepaper](https://polybase.xyz/Polybase_A_Decentralised_Query_Index_and_Storage_Protocol-v2.0.pdf) (in the "Economics" section).
Note: I'm a founder of Polybase.